# css3 rotate and stretch

Tags: html, image, css

How can I rotate an image and stretch it?

When I do this:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

It rotates the image and the size is still 1-1 on scale.
I want to rotate the image 90 degrees and then make the width 100%.

I tryed with img tag and with background image of the div

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `img` tag of course, and in css (I say this because i've tried, and I am almost sure), when you rotate something, for example of 90deg, the *height* become the *width*, and the *width* the *height*. **So** probably to fit you'll have to **use** `width` instead of `height`, and viceversa. The property `-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;` (and similar things for other vendors, i think) should let you to choose the center of rotation, 50% 50% should be the default value, placed in the middle (height and widht).

**[EDIT]**

I set up a JSfiddle, too: http://jsfiddle.net/eqqyvLdc/; In fact, I think you should use `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` in the CSS for the image, and edit the dimension of the parent div instead. What I said before I think it's still valid. I have commented the JSfiddle for more details. It's fun that if you delete the `display:block` from the image class/id, the image will be overflow outside the div!

Comment: I did a little example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0rw76z9r/1/

How can I make the width of this image 100%(inside the window) but the height will be the same?